# How to type hint a return value of Exception's subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

I have an abstract method in my base class, and I want all the subclasses to return an iterable of their expected `Exception` classes:

```
class Foo(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def expected_exceptions(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Bar(Foo):
    def expected_exceptions(self):
        return ValueError, IndexError

class Baz(Foo):
    def expected_exceptions(self):
        yield from self.manager._get_exceptions()
```

How do I type hint this return value? At first I thought of `-> Iterable[Exception]`, but that would mean they are instances of `Exception`, as opposed to subclasses.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Incidentally, what is `manager`? It seems to complicate the example somewhat. ;)

Comment: @gmds It's all just an example, in reality I'm creating an API that is meant to be extended by its users, and honestly I have no idea how they will fetch their errors. For all I know they might have an XML file with the possible errors listed, and they'll read it from there.

Comment: I see, that makes sense then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type), which specifies that you are returning a *type*, as opposed to an *instance*:

```
from typing import Type, Iterable

def expected_exceptions(self) -> Iterable[Type[Exception]]:
    return ValueError, IndexError
```